Connect to Azure SQL Server using windows credentials
I'm trying to connect to Azure SQL using on-prem AD account, which is synched to Azure AD.
I am able to connect using the SSMS when I run as a different user but programmatically it doesn't work.
It's an on-prem AD account and yes if we use the ActiveDirectoryIntegrated it overrides whatever credentials we specify and uses local machine AD id to login(which eventually fails as access is not granted). Is there no way we can authenticate programmatically using custom credentials? We have been recently informed by db team that we must use a AD account to authenticate to SQL Server, past 10 years we have been using SQL server and this change just came in so we are doing POC at the moment. I am not able to find any MS documentation that says that we cant pass custom credentials.
Also, since this will be a WebApp that will be hosted on IIS, is there a way we can do runas? If yes then what are the challenges involved?
Tried multiple connection strings but none seems to work. I get an error as

Login failed for user

public static void testrun()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "AZURESQLDEV";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "DataBaseName";
            builder.Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryPassword;
            builder.UserID = "DEVUser";
            builder.Password = "DEVPass";
            builder.TrustServerCertificate = true;
            builder.PersistSecurityInfo = false;
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [FRU].[FRU_BU_PLANT_PRECEDENCE_INFO]";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }

Also tried to explicitly authenticate the user and try login in using the below code
string username = "DEVUser";
string password = "DEVPass";
try
{
    if (AuthenticateUser(username, password))
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=DCA-DEV-123;Initial Catalog=DBATOOLS;User ID=" + username + ";Password=" + password;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Perform SQL operations using the connection

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid username or password.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
private static bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
{
    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
    }
} 

The error is:

Login failed for user 'DEVUser'

Stack trace :
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at TesSP.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\TesSP\Program.cs:line 36


Wasn't this asked like yesterday? You can impersonate by code, although, not sure how this azure stuff works, but i wouldn't bother, just use sql server accounts which work better

How do we impersonate by code to connect to SQL Server? I tried it doesn't work, also on IIS can we run the app as a different user?
